# How to pivot and get total amount each month

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have data like :
My table
[image]

My final results should be like this:

[image]

My SQL Statement:

```
    SELECT 'Q'+cast([Month_Quarter] as varchar) Month_Quarter,COALESCE([Zugänge],0) Zugänge,COALESCE([Abgänge],0) Abgänge
FROM
(
  SELECT DATEPART(QUARTER,[Monat]) [Month_Quarter],
       [Zu-, Abgang],
      Count(DISTINCT [Projektdefinition DB]) NoProjects

FROM AbZugänge 
GROUP BY DATEPART(QUARTER,[Monat]), [Zu-, Abgang]

) proj
 PIVOT (SUM(NoProjects) FOR [Zu-, Abgang] IN (Zugänge, Abgänge)) As pvt
  WHERE [Month_Quarter] is not null 
  ORDER BY Month_Quarter
```

BUT with this statement I am getting the results without the Amount column Zugang and column Abgang:

[image]

How can I edit the statement to get the aggregation amount columns?

Comment: This isn't even a pivot.   It's a simple GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can just wrap your query inside another select statement, then use GROUP BY. Something like this:

```
SELECT Month, SUM(ISNULL(column_name,0))
FROM (Your Query in here)
GROUP BY Month
```

Comment: Can you please give more information or can you  edit my query at the level where you think it may help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the point of the PIVOT in your original query. This looks like a typical aggregate is all that is required. See if this is what you need.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,Monat) [Month]
    , sum(case when [Zu-, Abgang] = 'Zugänge' then [Zu-, Abgang] else 0 end) as Zugänge
    , SUM(case when [Zu-, Abgang] = 'Abgänge' then [Zu-, Abgang] else 0 end) as Abgänge
    , SUM([GWU aktuell]) as [GWU Total]
    , SUM([GWU Planung aktuell]) AS [Plan Total]
    , COUNT(DISTINCT [Projektdefinition DB]) NoProjects
FROM AbZugänge 
group by DATENAME(MONTH,Monat)
```

Comment: Can't sum at this level because it's a nvarchar Data type

`sum(case when [Zu-, Abgang] = 'Zugänge' then [Zu-, Abgang] else 0 end) as Zugänge`  Error 245

Comment: Well we don't know what your tables are like because you didn't post them. Can you cast it as an int?

Comment: I have improved my Statement